# Post text input value to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a functional AJAX post that's working great.  My client requested an additional text input field, and for the life of me, I can't get it.  The script is long so I'll give you the relevant bits in hopes that it's a matter of syntax.

HTML for my input:

```
<input type="text" name="why" id="why" maxlength="70">
```

Javascript call

```
$(document).on("click", ".take-claim-link", function(){
var id= $(this).attr('data-id');    
var point= $(this).attr('data-point');
var val= $(this).attr('data-val');  
var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
var why = $("#why").val();

var follow = document.getElementById("follow-" + id + "-"+ type);
var followuser='0';
if (follow.checked) {
    var followuser = "1";
}


var takeurl = '/api/responseClaim.json';
var newPrice ='';   

var newData = $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: takeurl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { point: point, claimId: id, type: val,why: why,follow: followuser }
    })
(etc).
```

It returns nothing for "why".

The funny thing:  if I change the variable to `var why = 'sample why';` it passes.  Likewise, if I change my input to `<input type="text" name="why" id="why" maxlength="70" value="some value">` it reads it.  So I think the problem is in the way I'm defining it.

But what?  I've also tried `var why = $("input#why").val();` and `document.getElementById("why").value;`

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other element with `why` as `id`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There could be another element with same `id="why"` in your HTML code. So try to search for it. Or change the id of above input to something else.

Optionally you can try to get that input value with:

```
var why = $('input[name="why"]').val();
```

Hope it helps.